# How to refer to VBProject in a different xlsm Workbook?

Tags: vba, excel

I need to write a macro that will create a new workbook `test.xlsm` and assign a `vb` code to it's first sheet (Sheet1).

```
 Sub AddCode()
        Dim wb As Workbook
        Set wb = Workbooks.Add
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)

        Dim code As String
        code = "Sub test()" & vbCrLf & MsgBox "Test" & vbCrLf & "End Sub"
        Dim lineCount As Integer

        With wb.VBProject.VBComponents(ws.Name).CodeModule
            lineCount = .CountOfLines
            If lineCount > 0 Then
                .DeleteLines 1, lineCount
            End If
            .AddFromString code
        End With

      wb.Save FileName:="C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\test.xlsm", FileFormat:=52
      wb.Close
    End Sub
```

I get `subscript out of range` error . I presume that I am referring to the wrong vb project

(PS: by "assigning a code to it's first sheet" I mean the following: `Right Click on the Sheet1 -> View Code -> Paste my code to the Module   )`

Comment: `wb.VBProject.VBComponents(ws.Name)` - do you really have sheet with _code_ name `Sheet1` in test2.xlsm?

Comment: Yes I do have that sheet. I am not sure if it is a code name, but it says "Sheet1"

Comment: I have only one sheet there, so I tried pointing to it as `Worksheets(1)`

Comment: http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/excel-vba-sheet-names.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save your workbook as an add-in and then load it into excel. Then you can add a reference to the add-in from the VBE editor and access the functions/subs.

You can google Chip Pearson's tutorials, and other such material for such stuff. Here is where he explains how you can manipulate the Visual Basic Editor to programmatically add code, etc. Possibly useful in your case.

Ref: http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/VBE.aspx

Just for ease of reference (all from the above website by Chip Pearson)

Adding A Module to a Project:

```
Sub AddModuleToProject()
    Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent

    Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
    Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_StdModule)
    VBComp.Name = "NewModule"
End Sub
```

and most importantly, adding a Subroutine to a Module:

```
 Sub AddProcedureToModule()
    Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
    Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
    Dim LineNum As Long
    Const DQUOTE = """" ' one " character

    Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
    Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents("Module1")
    Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule

    With CodeMod
        LineNum = .CountOfLines + 1
        .InsertLines LineNum, "Public Sub SayHello()"
        LineNum = LineNum + 1
        .InsertLines LineNum, "    MsgBox " & DQUOTE & "Hello World" & DQUOTE
        LineNum = LineNum + 1
        .InsertLines LineNum, "End Sub"
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Another way is simply to do the following

```
Dim FileNameStr as String, Path as String
' Set these two to the correct strings
Dim wb as Workbook

set wb = workbooks.open(Path & "\" & FileNameString)
Application.Run (wb.Name & "!NameOfYourMacro")
```

This way you can run a macro without arguments

---

Of course that's just the core of the code. You still need to clean up afterwards, close workbooks, maybe set them as readonly when opening, etc. but you get the drift.

Comment: so was this helpful for your case?

Comment: +1 Thank you. But I had a different question. I needed to add a VB to a second workbook

Comment: I had referred to the path to the solution ... viz. Pearson. Have a look here http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/VBE.aspx

Comment: It also shows how to create a new module in a new excel file, and programmatically add code to that.